# How to move a folder into an non emty repository using git bash?

Tags: git

While using a Git for moving that folder it shows an error message that `destination pathe 'codeignetormail' already exits and is not an empty directory`

1. Inside the repository source file I have a folder name Codeignetor
2. And sub folder-appilcation and system inside main folder Codeignetor.
3. I need to move 'test' sub folder into the Codeignetor main folder using Git Blash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading the blah blah, i guess this is the answer

```
test
    mail
    sub folders
codeignetor
    application
    system
mail
    file.txt
```

**I need to move that folder into the Codeignetor folder**. which i guess,..

You can try in two steps..

```
git mv
```

or

```
mv test/mail codeignetor
git rm -r mail
git add codeignetor/mail
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the directory as normal by dragging the folder around with the mouse, or using `mv`, or however you like to do it.  Then, from Git,

```
git add --all .
```

Git will automatically detect that you have moved things around.